# xcode 3.2.3 compiler warning

Tags: iphone, xcode, compiler-construction

'ld: warning: directory '/Volumes/Skiiing2/CD/ViewBased/Unknown Path/System/Library/Frameworks' following -F not found'

I am getting this error for quite some time now...

I also upgraded to latest xcode 3.2.3 with latest iphone os 4.0 but still getting this error. I found some posts about it telling to remove invalid framework search path from project settings, but my framework search path shows empty path.

Any ideas? Is this xcode bug or invalid project settings file?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its trying to find a non-existant volume, possibly a removable one. It was most likely something that you used in the past but then got rid off.

Empty the Xcode cache under `Xcode>Empty Caches...` and then clean all targets. That usually stops Xcode from looking for old files.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just tried that: emptying cache and cleaning all targets but this warning insists keeping appear... Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check both your Project settings and your Target settings (by selecting the target in the left pane and doing Get Info). Then search for any build settings which mention "Frameworks" and use the cog icon menu to remove any definitions at the Target level.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks lucius and TechZen for your kind help.

I couldn't find anywhere the problematic setting within xcode project settings view... but finally(!) found a way to fix it as follows.

What I did was opening the .pbxproj file from my Windows XP computer using Word Pad (much better formatting than Notepad) and simply remove the invalid 'skiiing2' from FRAMOWORK_SEARCH_PATHS section.
Of course you need to quit xcode before doing that and clean your project.

Do that with caution since you can easily corrupt this file and I'm sure recommending to backup this file before making any changes.